# Has anyone succeeded to install the JOSSO Agent on a JBoss AS 7.1.1?

Tags: jboss7.x, josso

I'm using JOSSO version 1.8.8 (also tried 1.8.9.SNAPSHOT)...

I used the installer (as posted on www.josso.org) to install the agent and the sample partnerapp. When I start JBoss, the sample app won’t deploy.

```
14:46:39,982 ERROR [org.josso.jb7.agent.JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error starting SSO Agent : Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: urn:org:josso:agent:core: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: urn:org:josso:agent:core
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parseBeanFromExtensionElement(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:277)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:155)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:49)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1255)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1245)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:84)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:180)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:161)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:51)
  at org.josso.agent.config.SpringComponentKeeperImpl.<init>(SpringComponentKeeperImpl.java:51) [josso-agents-bin-1.8.9-20131023.185250-4-jaxws.jar:]
  at org.josso.agent.config.SpringComponentKeeperFactoryImpl.newComponentKeeper(SpringComponentKeeperFactoryImpl.java:33) [josso-agents-bin-1.8.9-20131023.185250-4-jaxws.jar:]
  at org.josso.agent.Lookup.getComponentKeeper(Lookup.java:125) [josso-agents-bin-1.8.9-20131023.185250-4-jaxws.jar:]
  at org.josso.agent.Lookup.lookupSSOAgent(Lookup.java:102) [josso-agents-bin-1.8.9-20131023.185250-4-jaxws.jar:]
  at org.josso.jb7.agent.JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator.<init>(JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator.java:65) [josso-jboss7-agent-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.8.9-SNAPSHOT]
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.getInstance(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:378)
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:210)
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

14:46:40,044 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."josso-partner-jboss7-app-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.ear"."josso-partner-jboss7-web-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."josso-partner-jboss7-app-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.ear"."josso-partner-jboss7-web-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "josso-partner-jboss7-web-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "josso-partner-jboss7-app-1.8.9-SNAPSHOT.ear"
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018096: Error instantiating container component: org.josso.jb7.agent.JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.getInstance(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:386)
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:210)
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  ... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting SSO Agent : Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: urn:org:josso:agent:core
  at org.josso.jb7.agent.JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator.<init>(JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator.java:73)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.getInstance(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:378)
  ... 8 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: urn:org:josso:agent:core
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parseBeanFromExtensionElement(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:277)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:155)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:49)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1255)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1245)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:84)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:180)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:161)
  at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:51)
  at org.josso.agent.config.SpringComponentKeeperImpl.<init>(SpringComponentKeeperImpl.java:51)
  at org.josso.agent.config.SpringComponentKeeperFactoryImpl.newComponentKeeper(SpringComponentKeeperFactoryImpl.java:33)
  at org.josso.agent.Lookup.getComponentKeeper(Lookup.java:125)
  at org.josso.agent.Lookup.lookupSSOAgent(Lookup.java:102)
  at org.josso.jb7.agent.JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator.<init>(JOSSOJASPIAuthenticator.java:65)
  ... 14 more
```

Ik made no changes to the JBoss AS, just extracted it to a folder and tried to setup JOSSO.

(fyi, I did exactly the same on a TomCat server, and there everything went fine)

Any ideas?

(Also, I've already tried 4 times to post this topic on the JOSSO discussion board, but it seems they won't allow it...)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable TRACE level logging for org.jboss.modules package in the logging subsystem of your standalone.xml/domain.xml file.
2. Remove the INFO level of Console and or FILE appender so that those TRACE level logs do get logged in the server.log file

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">  
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
   ```

   edit or remove

   ```
   <level name="INFO"/>  
       <formatter>  
           <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>  
       </formatter>  
   </console-handler>  
   <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
   ```

edit or remove
            `<level name="TRACE"/>`

add this in the appropriate section

```
        <logger category="org.jboss.modules">  
            <level name="ALL"/>  
        </logger>
```

It is quite possibly a dependency that didn't get loaded.

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the problem so much as it is a suggestion on how to debug the problem...